# How to make ofs not overwrite at the beginning

Tags: c++

I wanted to make a program in C++ that would read the content of one text file and write it in the opposite order in another file. For example, if in file one there would be:

```
Hi This
Is File
```

I want File 2 to become:

```
eliF sI
sihT iH
```

I wanted to do it this way:

```
char c;
while(ifs.get(c))
{
    ofs.seekg(0);
    ofs.put(c);
}
```

But every time it overwrites the charcter and the output is just the last one.

I managed to make a program that looks like this:

```
int i=0;
char chars[100];
while(ifs.get(chars[i])) i++;
cout<<endl<<endl;
for (; i>=0; i--)
    cout<<chars[i]<<"   ";

for(; i>=0; i--)
    ofs << chars[i];
```

But I would like to make one that doesn't use an array. Is there a way to make something that it won't overwrite just write before the letters?

Comment: I think what you want to do is *insert* the character into the file, shifting the existing contents one character to the right. There is no way to do that (other than doing it explicitly yourself, but you probably don't want to do that either). However, using `seek`, you could *read* the input file backwards.

Comment: I think rici has the right idea. There are three answers here so far, and all of them miss the whole point of the question: how to do this *without using an array*. That implies you can't use a string, a vector, or a buffer either.

Answer (score 0):

1. Read the characters from the input file and copy them to a vector.
2. Save the characters from the vector in the reverse order to the output file.

```
std::vector<char> chars;
char c;
while ( ifs.get(c) )
{
   chars.push_back(c);
}

size_t size = chars.size();
for ( size_t i = size; i > 0; i-- )
{
   ofs.put(chars[i-1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it following way:

```
#include<sstream>
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string s,s1="";
    freopen("input.txt","r",stdin);
    freopen("output.txt","w",stdout);
    while(getline(cin,s))
    {

        s1+=s;
        s1+='\n';
    }
    for(int i=s1.length()-1; i>=0; i--)
        cout<<s1[i];
    return 0;
}
```

Here first read all the entire lines form the inputfile.(please name it `input.txt`. and create a file named`output.txt` at the same directory where the code lies in). Then each line add with an empty string `s1` and add a `newline` after each line. At last print it `reversed` order. This is the solution. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

The most optimal way to solve it would be opening the source file in binary mode (text mode implies reading from top), say, with `fopen(filePath, "rb")` and then reading it buffer by buffer *backwards from the bottom*. Each buffer character would be then written to the output from the input buffer starting from the end.

```
FILE* pInFile  = fopen(filePathIn, "rb");
FILE* pOutFile = fopen(filePathOut, "w+b");

reverseFileRead(pFileIn,
    [=](char* p, size_t bufferSize){reverseBufferWrite(pOutFile, p, bufferSize);});
```

Where

```
void reverseFileRead(FILE* pInFile, std::function<void(char*, size_t)>&);

void reverseBufferWrite(FILE* pOutFile, char* buffer, size_t bufferSize);
```

That is more of blueprint and implementation would require dealing directly with file buffer which is more of a routine but can definitely be accomplished given some time for implementation and debug. The end of line characters need special treatment in this case, of course.

Comment: Why open in binary mode?  I would guess a Windows user of this program does NOT want \x0d\x0a converted to \x0a\x0d.

Comment: Made a change (last statement). The text mode is always reading from the begin to end not reverse.